# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'statsmodels' even after i have installed it in conda/python

Tags: python, module, jupyter-notebook, importerror, statsmodels

enter code here[this is the image of pip where I installed statsmodels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5R58.png)

[This is the error I get when I run the code below][2]

```
from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import seasonal_decompose
from dateutil.parser import parse
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/selva86/datasets/master/a10.csv',parse_dates=['date'], index_col = 'date')
result_mul = seasonal_decompose(df['value'],model='multiplicative',extraplote_trend = 'freq')
result_add = seasonal_decompose(df['value'], model='additive',extrapolate_trend= 'freq')
plt.rcParams.update({'figure.figsize': (10,10)})
result_mul.plot().subtitle('Multiplicative Decompose', fontsize=22)
result_add.plot().subtitle('Additive Decompose', fontsize=22)
plt.show()
```

``

[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hC9tg.png**these are the issues I have been facing please help me, anyone, I have posted my issue in the uploaded screenshots. I was not able to install statsmodels module even when It was installed it several times **

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, edit it into the question formatted as a code block.

Comment: Now you can find the code , please look and provide the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me
`pip install statsmodels` or `pip3 install statsmodels`

Answer (score 0):

I think you have **0.11.1** version of statsmodels. However, **import statsmodels** worked in my Jupyter with statsmodels version **0.10.1** but please work on below points and let me know:

1. Use **import statsmodels.api as sm** , as recommended in https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/importpaths.html
2. If above doesn't help, please uninstall statsmodels and use the following command to re-install it: **conda install -c anaconda statsmodels**. It is recommended in https://anaconda.org/anaconda/statsmodels . After this, try to import.

Comment: python -m pip install statsmodels----- this worked for me